# Saving a tab with a temporary name in Excel VBA as a separate csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which creates a tab, named by a cell - every time I run the macro - this tab has different name. I have to save only this tab as a separate csv file.

For now I have the code below - it saves all 2 tabs to a specified location. I would be really grateful for any ideas how I can manage this !

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
myPath = "\\F:\ABC\INPUT\"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet.Index).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & mySheet.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next mySheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Do you not need a loop then? Can you clarify a little bit more? Right now you loop over each sheet: `For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Probably I do not need a loop and ~For Each~ part - just cannot figure out how I can save one tab with impermanent nameas a csv file. I know how to do this if I know the tab name : `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A_123").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\path\file.csv"`,  but have trouble with the same problem - if I do not know the name of the tab

Comment: You can use the sheet codename perhaps.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it - what do you mean by codename?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename . You can see the worksheet codename in the VB Editor (lefthand side). Assuming it is `Sheet1`, you would just do `Sheet1.Copy` instead of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A_123").Copy`.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+R in the VBE; under "Microsoft Excel Objects" you'll find all worksheet modules (along with a `ThisWorkbook` workbook module). The "code name" is the actual programmatic name of the sheet module, which you can change in the *properties* toolwindow (F4) by setting the `(Name)` property to any valid VBA identifier, which you can then use as-is in code to refer to *that specific worksheet* instead of pulling it from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. Note that this only works if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time (i.e. in the workbook that contains the VBA code).

Comment: In the project explorer, worksheets look like `Sheet1 (Sheet1)` - the first is the code name, and the parenthesized name is the "tab name" which the user can change on a whim. Changing a sheet's code name can't be done from Excel. Using code name is much more robust than using the sheet/tab name, because users can't easily change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you mentioned "I have a macro which creates a tab, named by a cell", so I am assuming that the tab is created based on the value in that cell. If that is the case, you may simply read the value of that cell in a vba variable. Something like:

```
Dim tabName as string
tabName = sheets("SheetName").range("A1").value 'if the cell for creating the sheet is A1
```

Now, use this variable to rename the file generated. Like,

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tabName).Copy 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\path\" & tabName & ".csv"
```